# Fundamental Group of Polygons

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, path-connected

[image][image][image]

In Kosniowski's book "A First Course in Algebraic Topology", he used Van Kampen's theorem to calculate the fundamental group of given pictures. He defined the first open set, for example for $X_1$ is $U_{1,1}=X_1-b$. But I think $U_{1,1}$ is not path-connected, so Van Kampen's theorem cannot be used.

If I am wrong, can someone explain why $U_1$ is path-connected? Maybe he means that in $X_1-b$ we also remove the region bounded by $b$?

Comment: Are you removing only the loop or also the region that it bounds?

Comment: @Randall In previous example, when there is no $b$, he removed $a_i$, this means only boundaries. If he removed the region that it bounds I understand why $U_1$ is path-connected, but I am not sure.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the pictures represent. What is the space whose fundamental group we're computing? What do the arrows mean?

Comment: If the region bounded by $b$ is **not** part of the space, then $X_1-\{b\}$ is path-connected. I don't have a copy of the book, so I don't know what the context is.

Comment: @Karl the space is given by the arrows and region bounded by the arrows. If you've seen the calculation of fundamental group of torus or Möbius strip before, it's similar to that

Comment: @Kevin.S I'll add the complete explanation from the book.

Comment: Judging by the context, the part bounded by $b$ is not part of each of the spaces $X_i$. Note that the author says that each $U_{i,1}$ strongly deformation retracts to the boundaries as illustrated in Fig. 25.9, which are certainly connected, which means that the author also thinks $U_{i,1}$ are connected. Similarly, the author says that each $U_{i,2}$ deformation retracts onto the circle $b$, which means that the disc bounded by $b$ is not included in the space, otherwise you'd get some sort of projective space-like thing that wouldn't be homotopy equivalent to a circle.

Comment: @ElliotYu by disc bounded by $b$ do you mean the triangle bounded by $b$?

Comment: Yes. Well, once you put on topology goggles, triangles are discs, so yeah.

Comment: @ElliotYu thank you for your explanation